# convert to PKCS12

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, tomcat

I am new at tomcat and took a server over from someone that is no longer here, i had to renew a cert on the server but i see it uses a format "PKCS12" i received the email from the cert authority but that format was not in there.

the server is running ubuntu with tomcat.
I have used the following command to request the cert that i have received:

```
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /home/"certname_year".key -out /home/"certname_year".csr
```

i have received the following formats

```
- Available formats:
       as Certificate (w/ chain), PEM encoded xx.cer
       as Certificate only, PEM encoded       xx_cert.cer
       as PKCS#7, PEM encoded                 xx.crt
       as PKCS#7                              xx.p7b
   as Root/Intermediate(s) only, PEM encoded  xx_interm.cer
```

I have googled and tried a couple things but nothing seems to work, would appreciate assistance.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This line fixed my problem"

openssl pkcs12 -export -out hostname.pfx -inkey xxxx.key -in xxxcert.cer

Note: if you have a keystore pass input it when prompted.